# Using ABBYY's Linux CLI via a VM in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, command-line-interface, abbyy

I'm working on a project for my job and it involves the ABBYY finereader to OCR documents. I am working in Windows at the moment in C# and unfortunately just found that ABBYY only supports a Linux CLI. Would it be possible/advisable for my program to launch a VM that ran the Linux command line inside it, to launch ABBY within it, and process the jobs required?

Other than that, I can't see how I could automatically get ABBYY to run unless I schedule jobs based on time intervals.. it would be nice to have stricter control over when it runs though.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what specific package from ABBYY (the software manufacturer) you are using.  Sounds by your description that you are using FineReader Engine SDK for Linux, and what version X.X?  Then I may be able to suggest further.